# "Read more" over image

Tags: css

Have small isue with image sizes while using "read more" button on image. Im trying to make image look smaller when using computer, but keep same size for mobile version. When im changing size of image for pc version, image getting too small for mobile version.

```
    <style>
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}


.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}


.container .btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80%;
  left: 80%;
  transform: translate(-80%, -80%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-80%, -80%);
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.container .btn:hover {
  background-color: black;
}</style>

<div class="container">
  <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/jaunaudzes-kopšana.jpg" alt="Jaunaudzes kopšana">
  <button class="btn">Rādīt vairāk</button>
</div>
```

pc version image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESHdO.jpg
phone version - https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yrPi.jpg

So i want to make pc version image smaller and keep same size for mobile. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use media queries to solve your issue. In the code below, whenever the screen size is greater than 480px, then the code will "execute".

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  .container img {
     width: 80%;
     height: auto;
  }
}
```